# Lighbox2 doesn't work for image gallery. Working on VS code v.1.35 Kali linux

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, lightbox2

I'm trying to make a gallery on my site. I download lightbox2 and drop lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js and lightbox.min.css into my site's folder. Made a link for both of them and then did the following code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/lightbox.min.css">
<script src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="gallery_1">
                        <a href="../media/thumbnails/thumb1_1.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery"><img src="../media/thumbnails/thumb1_2.jpg"></a>
                        <a href="../media/thumbnails/thumb2_1.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery"><img src="../media/thumbnails/thumb2_2.jpg"></a>
                        <a href="../media/thumbnails/thumb3_1.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery"><img src="../media/thumbnails/thumb3_2.jpg"></a>
                    </div>
```

Based on a tutorial i've watched that is supposed to work but yet do nothing. The guy running the tutorial is using windows while i'm using linux. Is there anything else i need to do?

Comment: You're going back one folder to add the css file, but not for the js file - can you upload an image of your folder structure?

Comment: can you share demo?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. It was caused due to wrong path to the js file